# Filter method return just the first item Android

Tags: android

I have `RecyclerView` and I tried to make filter to search into recycler item  and its working , but when I use it and type any thing the result is just the first item of list.

This is the Filter method

```
 private List<Data> filter(List<Data> datas, String newText) {
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();

    final List<Data> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Data data : datas) {

        final String text = data.getTODO_TITLE().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(newText)) {
            filteredModelList.add(data);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

and this is the menu

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String searchQuery) {
            final List<Data> filteredModelList = filter(dbList, searchQuery);
            filteredModelList.indexOf(searchQuery);
            List <Data> search =filteredModelList;
            todoRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            recyclerAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(search);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return false;}});
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Comment: i already gave you a working adapter source code, why dont you use it?

Comment: i cannot know how to use the adapter and i tried to use another method

Comment: what dont you know? just create the adapter, `add()` some data to, and use it in `setAdapter` method, whats unclear in those 3 steps?

Comment: ok if it is still not clear [those](http://pastebin.com/QHifmxNm) 8 lines of code shows how to do that, just place them in your Activity#onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Why you are creating new instance of Adapter everytime you search?

`recyclerAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(search);`

Instead create in once and call `recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: when i remove recyclerAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(search);

and run the app , nothing to show

Comment: you have to take it as global and set the adapter!